How to make Ubuntu autoinstall yaml to choose a ram block disk /dev/ram0?
Is it possible to make my autoinstall yaml storage section to choose a RAM block disk - /dev/ram0.
Can i use something like this? Will the ram disks be available during the boot?

type: disk
id: ram-disk
match:

path: /dev/ram0



